# How can I account for new categories in a categorical variable when making predictions with linear regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm building a linear regresion model to predict out-of-sample observations of a continuous variable based on some features, where some of them are categorical. My problem is that one of the categorical variables can have new categories in out-of-sample observations. I cannot know those new categories beforehand.

For some context, the variable to predict is a time variable that accounts for the time it took to make a delivery 'final_time', while the categorical variable is the 'driver_id'.

I'm using scikit learn in python

My first approach was to create a new variable with the total deliveries of each driver to use it as a new feature, and play with binary variables to use the driver_id coeficient if the driver is in the training dataset, and use the total deliveries if it is not. However with this approach i cannot see how to obtain the coefficient for the interaction between the binary variable and the total deliveries as in the training set there will be no observations that fulfill this feature.

Is there a simpler approach?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Categorical features are usually encoded using `OneHotEncoder`:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# Define sample dataset
df_train = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "driver_id": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
        "total_deliveries": [10, 21, 3, 4],
        "final_time": [15, 25, 21, 8],
    }
)

# Define encoder
encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore", sparse=False)

# Fit encoder
encoder.fit(df_train[["driver_id"]])
```

You can get the `driver_id` values seen during training directly from the encoder with `encoder.categories_[0]`.

The following function builds what you need.

```
def build_features(input, encoder, df_train):

    # Get one-hot encoded vectors for driver_id
    df = pd.DataFrame(encoder.transform(input[["driver_id"]]), columns=encoder.categories_[0])

    # Define total_deliveries column
    df["total_deliveries"] = [
        df_train[df_train["driver_id"] == driver_id]["total_deliveries"].sum()
        if driver_id in encoder.categories_[0]
        else df_train["total_deliveries"].mean()
        for driver_id in input["driver_id"]
    ]

    return df
```

If you call it like this:

```
df_test = build_features(pd.DataFrame({"driver_id": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]}), encoder, df_train)

print(df_test.to_numpy())
```

You'll get this as output:

```
[[ 1.   0.   0.   0.  10. ]
 [ 0.   1.   0.   0.  21. ]
 [ 0.   0.   1.   0.   3. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0.   1.   4. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0.   0.   9.5]]
```

Note that instead of adding the "total deliveries" when `driver_id` wasn't seen during training time, we're adding the "mean deliveries" of the training set. This is better then adding the total deliveries.